# Vuex State not Reactive without Page reload

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

The problem experiences entails the following setup:
Simple Nuxt Intallation v2^
Using Vuetify and Axios

I have already built an advanced app with a lot of extras using a real back-end, but decided to replicate the error on a simple new installation of Nuxt just to be able to create a repo for you guys. So the functionality of this demo might not be clear to you - but in real life the app is using tasks and projects. The user must be able to change the status of each task.

I cannot figure out how to go further with this app if I can't implement this feature. My first thoughts are that it **might be a bug with Nuxt / Vue** - *but I'm hoping someone can tell me I'm wrong!*

Seems simple?! Well, 7 Days later and I'm no closer to solving this little bug I am experiencing...

Well for your ease-of-access I have loaded a simple github demo showing just what the problem is with only 3 steps to reproduce the error.

https://github.com/BarryJamez/not-so-reactive-app.git

Steps: Once you have run 'npm run dev' - as follows:

Step 1: Start on the index page (http://localhost:3000)

Step 2: Click on 'View Tasks'

Step 3: Try to change the status of a task by pressing the buttons

Step 4: Now refresh the page and all of a sudden it works.

To repeat this problem, just navigate back to the home page, refresh (reload) the page and start again from step 1

I have tried a lot of things, but none of them worked:

**1. I have moved my entire child component housing the list of comments into the parent component to eliminate the passing of props being the problem.

2. I have used Vue.set and array.splice instead of just replacing the array item with an index
3. I have enabled watchers on these computed arrays and set 'deep' to true
4. I have played around with async and await by removing them and adding them on certain places.
5. I have used the $nextTick function to see if it was a render issue
6. I have placed the array in its own parent level state property (although the postId field in a child element in the array) - yet how else can I contain an object in a state - an object must have 'child' elements.
7. I have referenced the parent component computed properties instead of the props in the child component.**

My Page with the tasks:

```
<template>
  <v-container fluid>
    <v-row v-for="task in myTasks" :key="task.id">
      <v-col>
        <v-card class="ma-4">
          <v-card-title>{{task.title}}</v-card-title>
          <v-card-text>
            <p>{{task.description}}</p>
            <p class="blue--text">{{task.status}}</p>
          </v-card-text>
          <v-card-actions>

            <v-btn
              v-if="task.status == 'Active'"
              @click="onChangeStatus(task.id, 'Completed')"
            >
              Complete Task
            </v-btn>

            <v-btn
              v-if="task.status == 'Completed'"
              @click="onChangeStatus(task.id, 'Active')"
            >
              Incomplete Task
            </v-btn>

            <v-btn
                v-if="task.status == 'Active'"
              @click="onChangeStatus(task.id, 'Postponed')"
            >
              Postpone Task
            </v-btn>

            <v-btn
              v-if="task.status == 'Postponed'"
              @click="onChangeStatus(task.id, 'Active')"
            >
              Activate Task
            </v-btn>

          </v-card-actions>
        </v-card>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex'

export default {
  async fetch({store, route}) {
    await store.dispatch('tasks/getMyTasks', {
      sid: route.params.sid
    })
  },
  methods: {
    onChangeStatus(taskId, status) {
      this.$store.commit('tasks/changeTaskStatus', {
        taskId: taskId,
        status: status,
      })
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState({
      myTasks: state => state.tasks.myTasks
    })
  }
}
```

My store namespaced 'tasks':

```
export const store = () => ({
  myTasks: []
})

export const mutations = {
  setMyTasks: (state, tasks) => {
    state.myTasks = tasks
  },
  changeTaskStatus: (state, params) => {
    let index = state.myTasks.findIndex(el => {
      return el.id == params.taskId
    })
    state.myTasks[index].status = params.status
  }
}

export const actions = {
  async getMyTasks (vuexContext, params) {
    try {
      let {data} = await this.$axios.$get('/tasks.json')
      vuexContext.commit('setMyTasks', data)
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e)
    }
  }
}
```

I don't really want to have to reload the page every time a user lands on it as this defeats the purpose of SSR and SPAs.

IF YOU CAN PICK YOUR BRAIN please checkout the repo on Github and follow the steps above:
https://github.com/BarryJamez/not-so-reactive-app.git

Comment: The main difference I can see is that on navigating to `/tasks`, the request for `tasks.json` happens client-side. When loading `/tasks` fresh, the request happens server-side

Answer (score 1):

You are not defining state in your task store.
In store/tasks.js

```
export const store = () => ({
  myTasks: []
})
```

while it should be

```
export const state = () => ({
  myTasks: []
})
```

Comment: I was looking at your two comparisons for a while before I noticed the difference!

and viola it works like a charm.. Interestingly, a lot of other things are now also reactive (and I was about to give up on Nuxt for not being what the label said!)

Thank you so much! Clearly spending too much time looking at the same thing makes you blind :)